# Change website deliver country with Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrape the website http://www.yellowkorner.com/
By choosing a different country, all the prices will change. There are 40+ countries listed, and each of those must be scrapped.

My current spider is pretty simple

```
# coding=utf-8

import scrapy


class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.yellowkorner.com/photos/index.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('a::attr("href")').re(r'/photos/\d\d\d\d/.*$'):
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_prices)

    def parse_prices(self, response):
        yield None
```

How can I scrape price information for all countries?

[image]

Comment: share what you have done so far

Comment: this isn't a scrapy problem, you should check which requests are being done when you change that country, use something like `firebug` to debug requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the page with firebug and refresh. Inspecting the web page at the panel Network / Sub Panel Cookies you will see that the page saves de country information with cookies (see image below).

[image]

So you have to force the cookie "YellowKornerCulture" attribute values LANGUAGE and COUNTRY at the request. I made an example based on your code to get the available countries on the site and a loop to get all the prices. See the code below:

```
# coding=utf-8

import scrapy


class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.yellowkorner.com/photos/index.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):
        countries = self.get_countries(response)
    #countries = ['BR', 'US'] try this if you only have some countries     
    for country in countries:
        #With the expression re(r'/photos/\d\d\d\d/.*$') you only get photos with 4-digit ids. I think this is not your goal.   
            for url in response.css('a::attr("href")').re(r'/photos/\d\d\d\d/.*$'):
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), cookies={'YellowKornerCulture' : 'Language=US&Country='+str(country), 'YellowKornerHistory' : '', 'ASP.NET_SessionId' : ''}, callback=self.parse_prices, dont_filter=True, meta={'country':country})

    def parse_prices(self, response):
        yield {
        'name': response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()[0],   
        'price': response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract()[0],
        'country': response.meta['country']

    }
    #function that gets the countries avaliables on the site    
    def get_countries(self, response):
        return response.xpath('//select[@id="ctl00_languageSelection_ddlCountry"]/option/attribute::value').extract()
```

Took a certain time to figure this out but you have to erase another cookies that the site is using to choose the language page. Also I fixed the language value to English(US). The parameter `dont_filter=True` was used because you are requesting an already requested url each loop iteration and the default behavior of scrapy is don't repeat a request to the same url due performance reasons.

PS: The xpath expressions provided can be improved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it helps me a lot.