# How to trick geolocation for scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, geolocation, ip-geolocation

Currently, I working on a parser with scrapy of an online shop. I need to specify my location to get info about targeting-related stuff. Is there a way to set up scrapy in a way to change my location?
Can it be done by changing cookies?

**Update:** I am talking more about changing a location inside the country. Servers, who perform this operation have VPN which sends their connection randomly.
I saw this solution
[Change website deliver country with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531412/change-website-deliver-country-with-scrapy)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change website deliver country with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531412/change-website-deliver-country-with-scrapy)

Comment: Not really. I am talking more about changing a location inside the country. Servers, who perform this operation have VPN which sends their connection randomly.

Comment: some pages use database [MaxMind GeoIP](https://www.maxmind.com/en/home) which converts Address IP to GeoLocation - and it can be problem to change IP if it gets IP from lower level like TCP/IP. [Can the IP address for an HTTP request be spoofed? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/381393/can-the-ip-address-for-an-http-request-be-spoofed), [tcp - Is it possible to send HTTP packet via spoofed IP? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124184/is-it-possible-to-send-http-packet-via-spoofed-ip)